# Allowed memory size error in Tbs library

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinybutstrong

Hello i am facing the problem of Allowed memory size error. I have created the project in codeigniter, php and I have used Tbs library. Its worked fine but today it display the error:

> **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 258010 bytes) in
>   /home/abc/public_html/application/libraries/Tbs.php on line
>   4222**

Please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TBS + OpenTBS in order to merge an XLSX file , then there is a known problem fixed with OpenTBS version 1.9.2 : if the number of row to merge is quite numerous, then you can have a very long process or a memory size error when calling `$TBS->Show()`.

Use OpenTBS 1.9.2 or higher which is optimized for this point, and if the process is still long you can optimize more using the [OPENTBS_RELATIVE_CELLS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#opentbs_relative_cells) command.

Answer (score 1):

"Allowed memory size of XXXXXX bytes exhausted" is a typical error when you don't have, as it's own name says, enough memory available for the php query to run.

Try upgrading `memory_limit` variable on your `php.ini` file, or by setting up `ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXXM');` on your PHP file that you are running, being XXX the amount of Mb memory that you want to define.

If this isn't the case, you might have a bug in your software that is causing, i.e. a loop that is consuming memory without any control; but as you have said that it did work before...

Anyway, please check all the other answers from StackOverflow on this aspect:

[Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

[CodeIgniter Fatal error: Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726085/codeigniter-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-bytes-exhausted)

[Codeigniter - Allowed memory size exhausted while uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021336/codeigniter-allowed-memory-size-exhausted-while-uploading)

Comment: where should i write 'ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXXM');' because my project is live in server so i dont have php.ini file. I have to contact my host so may i write in my htaccess file ?

Comment: Nope, memory_limit  should only be written on PHP.ini file.

Comment: Also, ini_set function should be added on the top of your PHP file or header :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of occurs when your script is using too much memory. This can often happen in PHP if you have a loop that has run out of control and you are creating objects or adding to arrays on each pass of the loop. Check for infinite loops.

If that isn't the problem, try and help out PHP by destroying objects that you are finished with by setting them to null eg. $OldVar = null;.

Check the code where the error actually happens as well. Would you expect that line to be allocating a massive amount of memory? If not, try and figure out what has gone wrong.

Never upgrad memory_limit variable on your php.ini file, or by setting up ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXXM'); on your PHP file that you are running, being XXX the amount of Mb memory that you want to define.Letting application to eat memory he wants to is insane step.Try to find out bug does your application wants that much memory?? Find out